# All of them vs all of it

Tags: singular-vs-plural, pronouns

I want to refers C, N, O, P

Should I say "all of them have no allotropes" or "all of it has no allotropes?"

What's the difference? (Can I say : what's the differences?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should say "all of them", because the collection {C,N,O,P} doesn't have a name.  So you can't refer to the set as an *it* yet.

Comment: Whats the differences ? True or not?

Comment: If it's 1 thing that's different between X and Y, you can say *difference*, If it's >1 thing that's different between X and Y, you can say *differences*.  The number of X and Y doesn't change whether you say *difference* or *differences*.

Comment: What is the differences is true?

Comment: Or what are the differences?